# Blow up in holomorphic dynamics

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics, teichmueller-theory

Someone could explain the concept of blow up used in holomorphic dynamics? 
Specifically in the context of iteration of holomorphics functions. This concept could be taken to some of the deformation spaces of a particular function? Bibliography is very welcomed.

Comment: I've never heard the term "blow up" in the context of complex dynamics. are you maybe referring to renormalization or parabolic implosion ?

Answer (score 1):

Blow-ups are used in the construction of *parabolic curves* as described in Marco Abate's [paper on diagonalisation of non-diagonalisable discrete holomorphic dynamical systems](http://www.dm.unipi.it/~abate/articoli/artric/files/DiagonalizationOfNon.pdf).

[Brochero Martínez, Cano and López-Hernanz's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611019) gives a concise proof of existence in the $\mathbb C^2$-case.